# JSON or Python Library with administrative division types per country

Tags: python, geonames, wikidata

For use in a Python script, I am looking for a structured data source (e.g., a JSON file) that lists the administrative division types per country and country-like locations (e.g., Afghanistan has "provinces" > "districts" > "subdistricts" and Austria has "states" > "districts" > "municipalities"). Some countries will have complex and varied terms for administrative districts, and that's ok. If the data source doesn't capture the full breadth of terms in complex settings, that would be ok (e.g., the US has many county-like equivalents such as parishes, districts, etc.).

I don't need the names of each administrative district (e.g., "Wisconsin"), rather the name of the type of administrative district (e.g., "state").

Essentially, what I'm looking for is something like the table at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_administrative_divisions_by_country

Ideally, the data source would be regularly maintained. Crowdsourced is OK. Perhaps a Python library that pulls from known sources and is regularly maintained.

I think I could use Wikidata, but that would require a big messy body of time-consuming SPARQL queries. Perhaps I could use the GeoNames API to ask for first-order administrative division, second-order, etc, and scrape the district-type strings from the placenames, but that seems even more complex than Wikidata.

Comment: Have a look at https://gadm.org/